# How to split code into smaller functions

Tags: python, function, class, csv

I have an application that works.  But in the interest of attempting to understand functions and python better.  I am trying to split it out into various functions.

I"m stuck on the file_IO function.  I'm sure the reason it does not work is because the main part of the application does not understand reader or writer.  To better explain.  Here is a full copy of the application.

Also I'm curious about using csv.DictReader and csv.DictWriter.  Do either provide any advantages/disadvantages to the current code?

I suppose another way of doing this is via classes which honestly I would like to know how to do it that way as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

""" Description This script will take a csv file and parse it looking for specific criteria.  
A new file is then created based of the original file name containing only the desired parsed criteria.
"""

import csv
import re
import sys

searched = ['aircheck', 'linkrunner at', 'onetouch at']

def find_group(row):
    """Return the group index of a row
        0 if the row contains searched[0]
        1 if the row contains searched[1]
        etc
        -1 if not found
    """
    for col in row:
        col = col.lower()
        for j, s in enumerate(searched):
            if s in col:
                return j
        return -1



#Prompt for File Name
def file_IO():
    print "Please Enter a File Name, (Without .csv extension): ",
    base_Name = raw_input()
    print "You entered: ",base_Name

    in_Name = base_Name + ".csv"
    out_Name = base_Name + ".parsed.csv"

    print "Input File: ", in_Name
    print "OutPut Files: ", out_Name

    #Opens Input file for read and output file to write.
    in_File = open(in_Name, "rU")
    reader = csv.reader(in_File)

    out_File = open(out_Name, "wb")
    writer = csv.writer(out_File, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    return (reader, writer)

file_IO()

# Read header
header = reader.next()


stored = []
writer.writerow([header[0], header[3]])

for i, row in enumerate(reader):
    g = find_group(row)
    if g >= 0:
        stored.append((g, i, row))
stored.sort()

for g, i, row in stored:
    writer.writerow([row[0], row[3]])


# Closing Input and Output files.
in_File.close()
out_File.close()
```

Comment: You have quite a few questions in there, some of which are off topic (too broad) for SO. Please simplify and clarify just one question.

Comment: If you can get your code to work then questions about cleaning it up and improving the style are much better suited for the codereview site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok fair enough then the current question would be.  With the current code I get the follow error message  ./test.py
Please Enter a File Name, (Without .csv extension):  YouTubeVideoViewsDec2014
You entered:  YouTubeVideoViewsDec2014
Input File:  YouTubeVideoViewsDec2014.csv
OutPut Files:  YouTubeVideoViewsDec2014.parsed.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 56, in <module>
    header = reader.next()
NameError: name 'reader' is not defined

Comment: for what it's worth, the only code I would write off into a function here is `find_group`

Comment: @KrisArmstrong the reason your code is throwing that PARTICULAR error is, as you mentioned in the question text, that your main code doesn't know what `reader` and `writer` are since they're scoped to the code block. You return `(reader, writer)` which is good, but then you have to assign them when you call the function e.g. `reader, writer = file_IO()`. That said, it's going to be INCREDIBLY difficult to close those file handlers this way. I wouldn't do this.

Comment: @KrisArmstrong, if you're asking only about one error, you should provide a MCVE specific to that error; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I'd only separate `find_group`.

```
import csv

def find_group(row):
    GROUPS = ['aircheck', 'linkrunner at', 'onetouch at']
    for idx, group in enumerate(GROUPS):
        if group in map(str.lower, row):
            return idx
    return -1

def get_filenames():
    # this might be the only other thing you'd want to factor
    # into a function, and frankly I don't really like getting
    # user input this way anyway....
    basename = raw_input("Enter a base filename (no extension): ")
    infilename = basename + ".csv"
    outfilename = basename + ".parsed.csv"
    return infilename, outfilename
    # notice that I don't open the files yet -- let main handle that

infilename, outfilename = get_filenames()

with open(infilename, 'rU') as inf, open(outfilename, 'wb') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter=',',
                        quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    header = next(reader)
    writer.writerow([[header[0], header[3]])
    stored = sorted([(find_group(row),idx,row) for idx,row in
                     enumerate(reader)) if find_group(row) >= 0])
    for _, _, row in stored:
        writer.writerow([row[0], row[3]])
```

Comment: The only line I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around is     stored = sorted([(find_group(row),idx,row) for idx,row in
                     enumerate(reader)) if find_group(row)])  I think its just cause its one long line.   Is user input generally gathered from main. Curious about rather there is any pro/con to user input from function vs main.  Perhaps.  That would be the best solution.  Also if it matters I am working in Python 3.4.3 sop the raw_input() has changed to simply input()   Thanks for your help.  This really simplifies the original code.

Comment: for every row in `reader`, it does a `for` loop for `(index_of_row, row)`. If `find_group(row) >= 0` (that is to say, it finds one of your groups in that row), it adds the tuple `(find_group(row), index_of_row, row)` to the resulting list. That's all wrapped with a `sorted` call, so the whole thing is sorted by the group.

Comment: Note I did make an error in that code -- `if find_group(row)` should be `if find_group(row) >= 0`. The original code will list all rows that are either not found, or find something other than `aircheck` (since finding `aircheck` will return `0`)

Comment: I used `raw_input` because *YOU* used `raw_input` if your sample code. Nothing else has changed.

Comment: that line is equivalent to the [following `for` loop](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/29847b93c398be3501e3)